# Using the answer from one quadratic to solve another quadratic

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, problem-solving

a)Factorise the expression $2x^2-3x-35=(2x+7)(x-5)$

b)Use your answer to part a to solve the  equation $2(2x-1)^2-3(2x-1)-35$

How would I use my answer from a to solve b? I don't see  how it helps me solve it.

Comment: Well, quite clearly the second expression (part b) is obtained when you write $2x-1$ in the place of $x$ in the a-part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second expression is similar to first, just x has been replaced by 2x-1, so in your initial answer{ (2x+7)(x-5) },  replace x with 2x-1 and you should get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

substitute $2x-1=y$ i  the second equation, than use the factorization of the first equation.